# scrapy return empty json file

Tags: json, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy in order to extract data from websites.
When I'm opening the json result file it's always return empty.
My scrapy code is attached:

```
from scrapy import Spider


class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["youtube.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Motorcycle+Accident+Stunt+Rider+Knocks+Himself+Out+Stunt+Fail+2015"]

    def parse(self,response):
        questions = Selector(response).xpath('//a')
        for question in questions:
            item = StackItem()
            item['title'] = question.xpath(
                'a/text()').extract()
            item['url'] = question.xpath('//@href]').extract()
            yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're scraping the text element and href attribute of a nodes. You just have to change your xpath to get the result.

Try the following code

```
item['title'] = question.xpath('./text()').extract()
item['url'] = question.xpath('./@href]').extract()
```

Here's some output I got trying these in scrapy shell

```
In [38]: questions = Selector(response).xpath('//a')
In [39]: for question in questions:
             print question.xpath('./text()').extract()
[u'Motorcycle Accident Crash During Wheelie on the Highway Crash 2015']
[u'STREETFIGHTERZ']
[]
[u'Motorcycle Crash Compilation 2015 || Ep.#15 of October']
[u'Car Crash Weekly']
[]
[u'Motorcycle Accident Burnout On Highway Crash 2015']
[u'STREETFIGHTERZ']
[]
[u'Streetfighterz Ride The Murder Biz Ride 2015 Insane Motorcycle Stunts']
[u'STREETFIGHTERZ']
In [40]: for question in questions:
             print question.xpath('./@href').extract()
[u'/results?filters=movie&lclk=movie&search_query=motorcycle+accident+stunt+rider+knocks+himself+out+stunt+fail+2015']
[u'/results?filters=show&lclk=show&search_query=motorcycle+accident+stunt+rider+knocks+himself+out+stunt+fail+2015']
[u'/results?filters=short&lclk=short&search_query=motorcycle+accident+stunt+rider+knocks+himself+out+stunt+fail+2015']
[u'/results?filters=long&lclk=long&search_query=motorcycle+accident+stunt+rider+knocks+himself+out+stunt+fail+2015']
[u'/results?filters=4k&lclk=4k&search_query=motorcycle+accident+stunt+rider+knocks+himself+out+stunt+fail+2015']
[u'/results?filters=hd&lclk=hd&search_query=motorcycle+accident+stunt+rider+knocks+himself+out+stunt+fail+2015']
[u'/results?filters=cc&lclk=cc&search_query=motorcycle+accident+stunt+rider+knocks+himself+out+stunt+fail+2015']
[u'/results?filters=creativecommons&lclk=creativecommons&search_query=motorcycle+accident+stunt+rider+knocks+himself+out+stunt+fail+2015']
[u'/results?filters=3d&lclk=3d&search_query=motorcycle+accident+stunt+rider+knocks+himself+out+stunt+fail+2015']
[u'/results?filters=live&lclk=live&search_query=motorcycle+accident+stunt+rider+knocks+himself+out+stunt+fail+2015']
[u'/results?filters=purchased&lclk=purchased&search_query=motorcycle+accident+stunt+rider+knocks+himself+out+stunt+fail+2015']
[u'/results?filters=spherical&lclk=spherical&search_query=motorcycle+accident+stunt+rider+knocks+himself+out+stunt+fail+2015']
[u'/results?search_sort=video_date_uploaded&search_query=Motorcycle+Accident+Stunt+Rider+Knocks+Himself+Out+Stunt+Fail+2015']
```

You're already inside the `<a>` node so, use `./` to select elements inside it.